# How to remove text after the anchor tag | JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to text to be removed after the `<a>` tag i have tried following it remove the text but also removes the a tag.

```
<p class="ktext">We have some text here and after the link the text should be remove <a target="_blank" href="http://bit.ly/1hSmsAW">http://bit.ly/1hSmsAW</a> i am going to be removed.</p>


$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.ktext a').after().remove();
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/9uM8G/)

thanks in advance

Comment: what output you want ?.

Comment: I want to text to be removed after the <a> tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [node.nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ktext a')[0].nextSibling.remove();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9uM8G/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the next sibling of the anchor element

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $($('.ktext a').prop('nextSibling')).remove();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/J2K2Q/)

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/y47gr/

```
$(".ktext").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 2; }).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aamir give span tag to id which you wanna remove ' i am going to be removed.. ' Now write $('#abc').remove();Your text will be removed.

Comment: @Aamir If you want to remove only the text after <a> tag then what is the problem in giving span tag to your text.What is the issue?

Comment: i have no control over adding span... its dynamic - thanks for your answer